# Get all available Kubernetes versions in a given Azure region using .NET SDK

Tags: azure, kubernetes, .net-core, azure-aks

I am looking for a programmatic way to get available Kubernetes versions in a given Azure region using .NET SDKs. Something similar to the following Azure CLI command:

```sh
az aks get-versions --location eastus --output table
```

I am currently using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.ContainerService.Fluent.ContainerServiceManagementClient` class to create clusters and get details of existing cluster. But that does not seem to expose any way to get available Kubernetes versions in a region.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`REST API`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/aks/managedclusters/get)

```
public static async Task<string> GetAksVersions(string token, string subscriptionId, string location)
    {
        var aksVersionsUri = $"https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.ContainerService/locations/{location}/orchestrators?api-version=2017-09-30&resource-type=managedClusters";
        var json = await ExecuteGetOnAzureApi(aksVersionsUri, token);
        return json;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @sajeetharan. I ended up using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` package for this.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using `Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent` package and its `IAzure` interface. The code looks something like this:

```cs
var azure = Azure
    .Configure()
    .Authenticate(azureCredentials)
    .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);

var kubernetesVersions = await azure
    .KubernetesClusters
    .ListKubernetesVersionsAsync(region, cancellationToken);
```

The peculiarity of this call is that it returns much more results than `az aks get-versions`. So I had to find latest patch version of a specific Kubernetes version (`1.16.x`) that I was looking for. But that is necessary in any case.